# How to prohibit sliding at the Viewpager?

Tags: java

I'd just about the ActionBar to navigate.

```
    CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(m_bar);
    m_Pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.customviewpager);
    m_Pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    m_Pager.setCurrentItem(0,true);

    m_Pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you want?

```
m_Pager.setSwipeable(false);
```